# protocol buffer textformat parser giving error on backslash character

Tags: c++, parsing, escaping, protocol-buffers

I am trying to parse a file with the google::protobuf::TextFormat::Parser in c++. One of the string fields in my file contains backslashes. The parse function of the parser only seems to work with  double \ or / but not a single \ Is there a way to ignore single backslashes in my message? Or do I have to pre-process the file before parsing it.

Comment: Backslash is an escape character, just as it is in C++. How would you represent, say, a string containing a double quote, if not as `" \" "`? Whichever tool produced that text file should be fixed to properly escape special characters, including the backslash itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protobuf text format uses [C-style escaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C).  So, a backslash in the data must be represented as two backslashes in text format.  Similarly, if the string actually contains a double quote character, then you would need to put a backslash in front of it for the parser not to treat it as the end of the string.

So, yes, if you are taking raw text and injecting it into a text-format string, you need to preprocess the data to escape it.